# .htaccess - images only visible to members

Tags: .htaccess

How can I make some images visible to logged-in members only and hide them from non-members?
What i am concerned about is that if someone has the link to an image, they would be able to see it. How do I protect the images or the directory from non-members?

Let's say I have an image in a directory: `images/sample.jpg`

I looked at this question. My needs are the same but couldn't find the solution I was looking for. [Host problems securing content in members area folders with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126328/host-problems-securing-content-in-members-area-folders-with-htaccess)

Do I need to use `.htaccess` to protect that directory? If that directory is protected by `.htaccess` how can the members can see its contents?

**EDIT**
The members will be logged in using the login system that I have created using `php`.

Comment: In the provide question, they store the image in the DB, are you willing to do so?
Do you have a "real" login or it's just an .htaccess login?

Comment: I can store the images in the DB but then how can I display them in `php` without giving their name?  The only way that I know to link images in `php` is to do this: `<img src="images/<?php echo $image ?>" />`  This way I'll be displaying my directory `images` and then anyone can copy the entire directory.

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, I would store the picture in the DB. 
Then use the script in this resolve question : 
[How to retrieve images from MySQL database and display in an html tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793009/how-to-retrieve-images-from-mysql-database-and-display-in-an-html-tag)

At the begining of the script getImage.php. Just add a test to check if the uer is connected (Session/cookie/whatever you use for your user).

I have the feeling it's not the best so I will be glad if someone else propose a better solution, but at least It do the job.
(Ps: the SQL code is a bit old & maybe deprectaed, the purpose is here)